# Using pandas to scrape HTML: can it be used to scrape a table within a webpage?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I've done some basic webscraping using BeautifulSoup and urllib. However, I recently came across [this](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/quick-tip-the-easiest-way-to-grab-data-out-of-a-web-page-in-python-7153cecfca58) link that said that all you need to do to scrape a webpage like [this](https://apps.sandiego.gov/sdfiredispatch/) one is to run:

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html("https://apps.sandiego.gov/sdfiredispatch/")
print(tables[0])
```

I thought that is too good to be true, as a lot of times I struggle with beautifulsoup and urllib2.

I tried it to pull out the table on [this](http://crdd.osdd.net/raghava/ahtpdb/display.php?details=1) page :

```
url = "http://crdd.osdd.net/raghava/ahtpdb/display.php?details=1001"
tables = pd.read_html(url)
print tables[0]
```

and I got an output of:

```
                              0
0  Detailed description of 1001 ID
```

I was also trying some other methods, for example:

```
url = "http://crdd.osdd.net/raghava/ahtpdb/display.php?details=1001"
response = requests.get(url)
print response.content
```

or something like:

```
web_page = 'http://crdd.osdd.net/raghava/ahtpdb/display.php?details=1001'
page = urllib2.urlopen(web_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
print soup.get_text()
```

I know that there are lots of examples of web scraping using various methods on here generally. I've been following these examples as you can see, it's just that I can't seem to get this method to work for specifically my issue. If anyone could show me how they would improve any of these code snippets for my needs I would appreciate it.

Edit 1: As a side note I was trying the same code on a different webpage: https://dbaasp.org/peptide-card?id=3, but I guess this one is even more complicated.

Edit 2: There is something unusual based on Rafi's suggestion. I have attached a webpage and URL that I am trying to scrape [image: here]; Rafi you can see my URL is slightly different to what you used. And then when I tried to run your suggestion on my URL:

```
url = "http://crdd.osdd.net/raghava/ahtpdb/srcbr.php?details=1001"
table = pd.read_html(url)
print table[0]
print table[1]
print table[2]
print table[3]
print table[4]
print table[5]
```

The output I get is like this (truncated):

```
 Browse SOURCE in AHTPDB This page gives statis...
1                            Browse SOURCE in AHTPDB
2  This page gives statistics of SOURCE fields an...
3  Following table enlists the number of entries ...
4  Following table enlists the number of entries ...
5                                               Milk
6                                                834
7  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["...

                                                  1   \
0                            Browse SOURCE in AHTPDB
1                                                NaN
2                                                NaN
3  Following table enlists the number of entries ...
4                                                NaN
5                                             Casein
6                                                723
7                                                NaN

                                                  2   \
0  This page gives statistics of SOURCE fields an...
1                                                NaN
2                                                NaN
3                                               Milk
4                                                NaN
5                                             Bovine
6                                                477
7                                                NaN

                                                  3   \
0  Following table enlists the number of entries ...
1                                                NaN
2                                                NaN
3                                             Casein
4                                                NaN
5                                            Cereals
6                                                419
7                                                NaN

                                                  4        5       6   \
0  Following table enlists the number of entries ...     Milk  Casein
1                                                NaN      NaN     NaN
2                                                NaN      NaN     NaN
3                                             Bovine  Cereals    Fish
4                                                NaN      NaN     NaN
5                                               Fish     Pork   Human
6                                                384      333     215
7                                                NaN      NaN     NaN

        7        8        9   \
0   Bovine  Cereals     Fish
1      NaN      NaN      NaN
2      NaN      NaN      NaN
3     Pork    Human  Chicken
4      NaN      NaN      NaN
5  Chicken  Soybean      Egg
6      177      159       97
7      NaN      NaN      NaN

                         ...                             16     17     18  \
0                        ...                          723.0  477.0  419.0
1                        ...                            NaN    NaN    NaN
2                        ...                            NaN    NaN    NaN
3                        ...                          384.0  333.0  215.0
4                        ...                            NaN    NaN    NaN
5                        ...                            NaN    NaN    NaN
6                        ...                            NaN    NaN    NaN
7                        ...                            NaN    NaN    NaN

      19     20     21     22     23    24  \
0  384.0  333.0  215.0  177.0  159.0  97.0
1    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
3  177.0  159.0   97.0    NaN    NaN   NaN
4    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
5    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
6    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
7    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN

                                                  25
0  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["...
1                                                NaN
2                                                NaN
3                                                NaN
4                                                NaN
5                                                NaN
6                                                NaN
7                                                NaN

[8 rows x 26 columns]
                         0
0  Browse SOURCE in AHTPDB
                                                   0
0  This page gives statistics of SOURCE fields an...
                                                  0   \
0  Following table enlists the number of entries ...
1  Following table enlists the number of entries ...
2                                               Milk
3                                                834
4  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["...

                                                  1       2        3       4   \
0  Following table enlists the number of entries ...    Milk   Casein  Bovine
1                                                NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN
2                                             Casein  Bovine  Cereals    Fish
3                                                723     477      419     384
4                                                NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN

        5      6        7        8        9   ...      12     13     14  \
0  Cereals   Fish     Pork    Human  Chicken  ...   834.0  723.0  477.0
1      NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  ...     NaN    NaN    NaN
2     Pork  Human  Chicken  Soybean      Egg  ...     NaN    NaN    NaN
3      333    215      177      159       97  ...     NaN    NaN    NaN
4      NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  ...     NaN    NaN    NaN

      15     16     17     18     19     20    21
0  419.0  384.0  333.0  215.0  177.0  159.0  97.0
1    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
3    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
```

I don't understand how this is similar to the screenshot that I showed? Is it because the 'details=1001' blocks this method because it's not written like a .php page?

Edit 3: This works:

```
url = 'http://crdd.osdd.net/raghava/ahtpdb/display.php?details=1001'
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
tab = bs.find("table",{"class":"tab"})
data = []
rows = bs.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

print data
```

Comment: The answer is yes. Other than that it is not clear what you want to improve. The output of your code looks right to me, that's the first non-empty table in the page.

Comment: So for example when I use Rafi's suggestion below, when I say 'for i in range (0,100), print table[i]'; nowhere in the output is the information in the attached screenshot (e.g. PMID, year). Then I wondered was I meant to change the range to start at 1001, since the first ID is 1001, but that didn't work either. I really appreciate the help, I'm clearly just not getting something. For example, could someone show me specifically how to pull out any field of the table that I have attached in the screenshot (e.g. the PMID) for entry 1001 (in the above picture) of the above table/URL/db? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should play around a little with the table location.
for example: I took the website you gave as an example and found a table there ([url](http://crdd.osdd.net/raghava/ahtpdb/srcbr.php)).
Then I tried the piece of code you tried but with a minor change:

```
url = "http://crdd.osdd.net/raghava/ahtpdb/srcbr.php"
tables = pd.read_html(url)
print tables[4]
```

and I got the table just fine(with the header - no problem to remove it later).

The reason for that, is that in the example code that you copied there was only one table (or more than one and the table they needed was the first one). Thats why `table[0]` gave them the table that they wanted. In the case I showed here, the website is using tables for layout and the first table is not the table that you are trying to get (its the fifth one in that case - which is why `table[4]` will work in that case)

Note: you might want to save it to a csv so it will be more easy to read:

```
url = "http://crdd.osdd.net/raghava/ahtpdb/srcbr.php"
tables = pd.read_html(url)
tables[4].to_csv("path/to/file.csv")
```

Following your info, try this please:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = 'http://crdd.osdd.net/raghava/ahtpdb/display.php?details=1001'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
tab = bs.find("table",{"class":"tab"})
print(tab)
```

You will need to clean it up, but all of the table's data should be available there.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I can see that the URL that you used is slightly different from the URL that I was talking about, and I can get your method to work on your webpage, but not on the one I was talking about. I have included a full explanation as 'edit 2' on the question if you could take a look. I really appreciate your effort though.

Comment: Thank you so much, based on this I was able to get it working and added it in to Edit 3 above. I appreciate it (I guess we're saying that we can't use pandas as easily as the original article that I read say I could/the data is structured differently?). Thanks again.

Comment: Nothing as as easy as it looks ;) If it helped please mark it as the answer. Cheers

Comment: sorry I had upvoted without clicking accept answer, have done it now.